# I need help with this

Tags: cipher

×]  ∆}|£¢|€  √¶  ℅|  £∆£•√  ¶¥ √°×¢  ^•£™×√π      ¥£}}¢    ¥£]×}π.

Hints:

1. use keyboard (not every keyboard)
2. the first word is I'm
3. Samsung 7

A friend give me this riddle and I just couldn't figure it out I looked at all the keyboards but nothing made sense.

Comment: It's a replacement cypher. I could write the answer here, but that wouldn't get you closer to solution.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the hint refers to

> a smartphone symbol keyboard, such as the one shown here: www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/tablets/samsung-galaxy-tab/how-to-access-special-keyboard-symbols-on-your-samsung-galaxy-tablet/

However, these are constantly being changed and updated, and I haven’t managed to find one that matches your cipher.

As Thomas Blue pointed out, this can be solved as normal cryptogram with some letter frequency analysis. It translates to:

> I’m pleased to be apart of this Gravity Falls family.

The answer is likely

> Pines, the surname of the main characters in the aforementioned TV show. Also, I have to wonder whether the cipher meant “a part of” or “apart of”.